# Nesting ViewSet routes in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've created 2 ModelViewSets like so (simplified for demonstration):

```
class SomeBaseViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SomeEventSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeObjects.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(SomeBaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "user": self.request.user,
            "some_context_key": False
        })
        return context

class AdminViewSet(SomeBaseViewSet):
    # Added in the HasAdminPermission
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasAdminPermission)

    # Different queryset filter (overriding `get_queryset` vs setting queryset for standardization)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeObjects.objects.all()

    # The context should have `some_context_key=True`, and `user=request.user`
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(AdminViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "some_context_key": True
        })
        return context
```

My router/url config looks like this

```
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'some_view', SomeBaseViewSet, base_name="some_view")

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

If I wanted to route `/api/some_view/admin` to the AdminViewSet, what's the best way to do that?

Things I've tried:

- `@list_route` on `SomeBaseViewSet`, but couldn't figure out the "right" way to wire it to my `AdminViewSet`
- Adding `url(r'^api/some_view/admin$', AdminViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"}))` to my urlpatterns (which sorta works but neuters the ViewSet a bit, and is generally really manual anyway):
- Having a dedicated `DefaultRouter` for the `some_view` viewset, which I then mount on `url(r'^api/some_view/')` - again hacky and pedantic to do with a large number of routes

Is there a "right" way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, or should I reach for a different solution to this problem (i.e. a filter or something)?

I've seen libraries like https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers, but that seems like overkill for my (fairly simple) needs.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if i've missed something but i've just tested and this works perfectly (the order is important):

```
router = DefaultRouter()
# this will overrides routes from the line below
router.register(r'some_view/admin', AdminViewSet) 
router.register(r'some_view', SomeBaseViewSet)
```

Comment: @Fitblip hey, this should be the accepted answer, simple and right way to do, just order matters and thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Define your admin viewset using a list route.  These params will allow you to perform a get request, with specified permissions(is authenticated and has admin perms), that extends this class. ie `/someview/admin` or `someotherview/admin`

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
class AdminViewSet(viewset.Viewsets):

    @list_route(methods=['get'], 
                  permissions=[permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasAdminPermission],
                  url_path='admin'
     )
     def admin(self, request):
          # All your custom logic in regards to querysets and serializing
          return serialized.data
```

Then you can extend your any viewset that needs an admin action route.

```
class SomeBaseViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet, AdminViewset):
    serializer_class = SomeEventSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeObjects.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(SomeBaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "user": self.request.user,
            "some_context_key": False
        })
        return context
```

You want to be careful with this because typically the param after your base route ie /someview/{param}/ is reserved for ID references. Make sure your id reference will not conflict with your detail route.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an answer to my own question, but I put a +50 rep bounty on this in case someone wants to chime in (@tom-christie maybe?).

Either way the way that I've solved it for my usecase is by using the `@list_route` and the `AdminViewSet`'s `.as_view()` function.

Something like this suffices:

```
class SomeBaseViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SomeEventSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeObjects.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(SomeBaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "user": self.request.user,
            "some_context_key": False
        })
        return context

    @list_route()
    def admin(self, request):
        return AdminViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"})(request)

class AdminViewSet(SomeBaseViewSet):
    # Added in the HasAdminPermission
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasAdminPermission)

    # Different queryset filter (overriding `get_queryset` vs setting queryset for standardization)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeObjects.objects.all()

    # The context should have `some_context_key=True`, and `user=request.user`
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(AdminViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "some_context_key": True
        })
        return context
```

And will allow one to have the url's routed accordingly (based on the name of the function), and enforce any extra things you need.

Comment: I think your misusing the as_view. The as_view in their documentation appears to be a url config function. Furthermore, if you decide to extend an admin action to more views you'll have to write more code. I will post my proposed solution

Comment: I guess the evaluation of `as_view` should be moved outside the `admin` list route, but otherwise that doesn't seem like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

good question. i'd check out DRF's detail_route for this -- this is an idiom i've used successfully in the past to create a one-off type of endpoint that hangs off of a viewset. HTH,

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions

Comment: `@list_route` is more appropriate for my use case here (as outlined in my answer above) since it doesn't take in a PK, nor does it need to. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Fitblip you're absolutely right -- detail_route does take in a PK, so not useful here. i appreciate the correction.

Comment: I appreciate the response! This question has been a bit of a ghost town 